# SQL Get rows based on 3 column values

Tags: sql-server

sorry for the title not sure how to summarize my needs. I have a dataset with the following rows

```
Select ID,User,[Row#],[Row2#],Types,Date from MyTable
```

| ID | User | Row# | Row2# | Types | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65930969 | 000080A8C8 | 1 | 1 | TYPE 1 | 9/18/2019 |
| 65948916 | 000080A8C8 | 2 | 1 | TYPE 1 | 10/3/2019 |
| 66074230 | 000080A8C8 | 3 | 2 | TYPE 2 | 11/12/2019 |
| 59544865 | 0001116BE4 | 1 | 1 | TYPE 1 | 10/30/2017 |
| 59736459 | 0001116BE4 | 2 | 2 | TYPE 2 | 12/11/2017 |
| 68676655 | 0001116BE4 | 3 | 1 | TYPE 1 | 9/17/2020 |
| 68794822 | 0001116BE4 | 4 | 2 | TYPE 2 | 10/20/2020 |
| 69067248 | 0001116BE4 | 5 | 3 | TYPE 2 | 11/30/2020 |
| 69722764 | 0001116BE4 | 6 | 4 | TYPE 2 | 1/28/2021 |
| 69902103 | 0001116BE4 | 7 | 5 | TYPE 2 | 2/24/2021 |
| 62646449 | 0014E0F7C1 | 1 | 1 | TYPE 1 | 10/1/2018 |
| 62646463 | 0014E0F7C1 | 2 | 2 | TYPE 1 | 10/1/2018 |
| 66279347 | 0027C08119 | 1 | 1 | TYPE 1 | 10/29/2019 |
| 66333035 | 0027C08119 | 2 | 2 | TYPE 2 | 12/5/2019 |
| 66640349 | 0027C08119 | 3 | 3 | TYPE 2 | 1/9/2020 |
| 66990998 | 0027C08119 | 4 | 4 | TYPE 2 | 1/21/2020 |
| 67020294 | 0027C08119 | 5 | 5 | TYPE 2 | 2/20/2020 |
| 69673544 | 0027C08119 | 6 | 6 | TYPE 1 | 1/19/2021 |

My goal is to get All Types = "Type 1" And the following Types = "Type 2" with the Higher Date (or Row2#) whatever is easier. This table shows the result needed.

| ID | User | Row# | Row2# | Types | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65930969 | 000080A8C8 | 1 | 1 | TYPE 1 | 9/18/2019 |
| 65948916 | 000080A8C8 | 2 | 1 | TYPE 1 | 10/3/2019 |
| 66074230 | 000080A8C8 | 3 | 2 | TYPE 2 | 11/12/2019 |
| 59544865 | 0001116BE4 | 1 | 1 | TYPE 1 | 10/30/2017 |
| 59736459 | 0001116BE4 | 2 | 2 | TYPE 2 | 12/11/2017 |
| 68676655 | 0001116BE4 | 3 | 1 | TYPE 1 | 9/17/2020 |
| 69902103 | 0001116BE4 | 7 | 5 | TYPE 2 | 2/24/2021 |
| 62646449 | 0014E0F7C1 | 1 | 1 | TYPE 1 | 10/1/2018 |
| 62646463 | 0014E0F7C1 | 2 | 2 | TYPE 1 | 10/1/2018 |
| 66279347 | 0027C08119 | 1 | 1 | TYPE 1 | 10/29/2019 |
| 67020294 | 0027C08119 | 5 | 5 | TYPE 2 | 2/20/2020 |
| 69673544 | 0027C08119 | 6 | 6 | TYPE 1 | 1/19/2021 |

Comment: can you just be Lil more clear about your required results?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Maybe using `ORDER BY` clause might help you out to get your required output if it's just about sorting.

Comment: your results don't align with your logic, eg user *0001116BE4* has TYPE 2 twice, which is not the TYPE 2 with the higher date.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
select ID,[User],Row#,Row2#,[Types],[date] from Mytable where [Types]='Type1'
Union All
select ID,[User],Row#,Row2#,[Types],[date] from
(
select ID,[User],Row#,Row2#,[Types],[date]
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition By [Types],[User] Order by Row2# desc) Serial
from Mytable where [Types]='Type2'
) a where Serial=1
```